# Type does not conform to Protocol 'URLConvertible'

Tags: ios, swift, string, protocols

When I imported the [URLNavigator library](https://github.com/devxoul/URLNavigator) along with the files exactly as implemented in the Example project - I got these errors in URLConvertible.swift file. Can anyone please look into it. Try google-ing a lot but couldn't find any solution.

Type 'String' does not conform to protocol 'URLConvertible'

Type 'URL' does not conform to protocol 'URLConvertible'

Comment: The example project seems to compile fine for me. What version of Xcode are you? And is the rest of your project in Swift 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that you probably have missed some files when you imported them. I created a new project and installed the framework through **[CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org/)** and it worked fine. You can download the project that I created [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zdodi94jw2y8kfg/URLNavigator.zip?dl=0) and since I´m using CocoaPods make sure to run the `.xcworkspace` project file.